# C# WPF two different DataContext in One Control while using MVVM and the secound property is every time the same

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, relativesource

First the code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataTransferModel.Output}" Background="Transparent" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" AlternationCount="2" Name="lvOutput" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,1">
                <UserControls:OutputTextBox Text="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                            IsReadOnly="True" 
                                            Grid.Row="2" 
                                            TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
                                            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedOutput, 
                                                            Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}
                                                            }" 
                                            />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the problem is that the property `Data` on the OutputTextBox control comes from the list, but the property `SelectedOutput` should come from the main DataContext the ViewModel. And the property `SelectedOutput` should be the same for every entry in the list. But currently it dosn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

does your listview is enclosed in  tags and if yes does the grid has the DataContext from the ViewModel? if yes it should work.

do you see any binding errors in your output window? maybe you should try using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see your real binding of SelectedValue.

EDIT: Please try a Type other then Grid, maybe ListView if it has the ViewModel DataContext.

```
<UserControls:OutputTextBox Text="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                        IsReadOnly="True" 
                                        Grid.Row="2" 
                                        TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
                                        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedOutput, 
                                                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}
                                                        }" 
                                        />
```

Comment: The next tag to outer scope is the grid from the list and the DataContext is set to the ViewModel on the Loaded event of the Window. But it don't work. :(

Comment: pls try Snoop to see what the actual binding of SelectedValue is.