# Bind a WPF View to couple of DataContexts

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

**Objective:** Set the visibility of a control based on the selected value of a `ComboBox`

**Issue:** The property that is being used to check the visibility is in the VM, however I don't know how to use it as `DataContext` is already defined to another object, i.e would I need to bind 2 datacontexts?!

**Details:**

I have a `CustomControl` that I load in my view associating to it a `DataContext` (a `List` of objects that is displayed as a grid:

```
<GUI:Counterparties_UserInputs x:Name="UserInputs" DockPanel.Dock="Right" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource counterpartiesDataView}}"/>
```

In that user control I have some `StackPanel` which visibility should be triggered based on the selection of a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CounterpartyTypes}}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCounterpartyType}"/>
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedCounterpartyType,Converter={StaticResource SelectedValueToVisible}}"/>
```

The issue I have is that the code behind is never hit as I don't find how to associate an "extra" `DataContext` to the view.

Here is my code behind:

```
public partial class Counterparties_UserInputs : UserControl
{
   ...

    public Counterparties_UserInputs()
    {
        // this.DataContext = _cptyUserInputsVM;
        _cptyUserInputsVM = new Counterparties_UserInputs_VM();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel where the `Property` "SelectedCounterpartyType" is never hit:

```
public class Counterparties_UserInputs_VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _selectedCounterpartyType;

    public string SelectedCounterpartyType
    {
        get 
        {
            return _selectedCounterpartyType; 
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCounterpartyType = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedCounterpartyType"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960561/c-sharp-wpf-two-different-datacontext-in-one-control-while-using-mvvm-and-the-se) already but it's not exactly what I am doing... So would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: What does your output window have to say when you run your application? It might provide some useful information.
Also, you can save some bother with the notification in every setter, please see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240387/notifypropertychanged-through-code/15240640#15240640

Comment: I have updated the top of the text (Objective and Issue), hopefully it is clearer. Thank you!